# Getting a HTML table out of a Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've had to dive into HTML recently using Bootstrap as the framework. We have the DataTables plugin that allow a user to export the table as .CSV. However when I open this table in a Bootstrap modal and as far as I'm aware there is no way to get around this, the table shows but not the buttons at the top.

I've had to go the alternative way and make my own button and do the .CSV creation myself. I was wondering what is the best way to get all the HTML in that table by ID.

Edit (Code)

The HTML for the modal is built in PHP and sent over JSON to then be appended by JS.

PHP

```html
$html_string_packinglist .= '<table id="packing_list_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">';
    $html_string_packinglist .= '<thead>';
     $html_string_packinglist .= '<tr>';
      $html_string_packinglist .= 
       '<th>Order Number</th>
       <th>Box</th>
       <th>Product Code</th>
       <th>Customer Key</th>
       <th>Quantity</th>';
      $html_string_packinglist .= '</tr></thead>';

     $html_string_packinglist .= '<tbody>';
      foreach($packing_list as $pl) {
       $html_string_packinglist .= '<tr>';
       $html_string_packinglist .= '<th>' . $pl->ORDER . '</th>';
       $html_string_packinglist .= '<th>' . $pl->BOX . '</th>';
       $html_string_packinglist .= '<th>' . $pl->PRODCODE . '</th>';
       $html_string_packinglist .= '<th>' . $pl->PCUSTKEY . '</th>';
       $html_string_packinglist .= '<th>' . $pl->SumOfQTY . '</th>';
       $html_string_packinglist .= '</th></tr>';
      }
     
     $html_string_packinglist .= '</tbody></table>';

   echo json_encode($html_string_packinglist);
```

Modal HTML

```html
<div class="x_content">
  <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg-packing" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal_packing_title"></h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body" id="packing_list" style="max-height: calc(100vh - 210px); overflow-y: scroll;">
          <p id="packing_modal"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" id="export_packing_list_button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" style="float: left;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Export </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javscript to append HTML (The id=packing_modal is appended with the data from PHP)

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // $('#ticket_modal').empty();

    $("#order_modal_view_packinglist_button").click(function(e) {
      var order = $("#myModalLabel").val();

      $('#packing_modal').empty();
      $('#modal_packing_title').empty();

      $('#packing_modal').append('<center><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i></center>');

      $.ajax({
        url: 'get_packing_list',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          "ID": order
        },
        success: function(data) {
          // Empty the title and the tickets
          $('#packing_modal').empty();
          $('#modal_packing_title').empty();

          // var zendesk_ticket_id_trim = $.trim(zendesk_ticket_id);

          // Add the ticket ID into the title and the body from Zendesk
          $('#modal_ticket_title').text("Packing List");
          $('#packing_modal').append(data);

          // Scroll to the bottom of the list
          var m = $('#packing_list');
          var height = m[0].scrollHeight;
          m.scrollTop(height);
        }
      })
    });
  }); 
  </script>
```

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: Apologies. Added and updated